# FileSystemObject code has started to throw an error

Tags: vba, vb6, excel, filesystemobject

Not sure why but the following code has begun to throw an unknown error. When the macro is run Excel stops responding.

- Why is this error occuring?
- What is an alternative route with the same functionality?

This code is located within an Excel 2010 xlsm file on a Windows 7 machine.

```
 Sub CopyFolderToCasinoDirectory()

        'reference Microsoft Scripting Runtime
        On Error Resume Next

        Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
        Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
        fso.CopyFolder _
              "\\xxxfileserve\department$\DBA\Opers\All Operators\yyy", _
              "\\xxxfileserve\department$\DBA\Cas\yyy", _
              True

        On Error GoTo 0
        Set fso = Nothing

    End Sub
```

ok - I've changed the pathways so that it is attempting to move less files - and it hesitates but does eventually run through. I suspect that the above is failing because there are too many files in the directory specified? Currently there are 753 files - maybe too much?

[RonDeBruin](http://www.rondebruin.nl/folder.htm) has given me lots of ideas of how to test or alter the logic. One possibility might be to use DeleteFolder first on the destination folder, and then CopyFolder the target folder over?

Comment: Remove `On Error Resume Next` What error do you get?

Comment: I've tried taking that line out and Excel just does not respond i.e crashes!

Comment: When you say "not responding", have you tried leaving it for a minute? It might be hanging whilst it copies a large amount of files.

Comment: @Bridge I've tried leaving it for several minutes and excel greys out and is `(Not Responding)` ...maybe if I was very patient it would come back but I think I'll look for a work around. I believe that copying all those files over everytime is a bit much really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for replying so late. I was not able to get hold of network directories and I wanted to test the code before posting it :)

Try this. Run the `Sub Sample()` Does it still hang? You will also see the Files getting transferred in a Windows Dialog Box.

```
Private Declare Function SHFileOperation _
Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "SHFileOperationA" _
(lpFileOp As SHFILEOPSTRUCT) As Long

Private Type SHFILEOPSTRUCT
    hWnd As Long
    wFunc As Long
    pFrom As String
    pTo As String
    fFlags As Integer
    fAborted As Boolean
    hNameMaps As Long
    sProgress As String
End Type

Private Const FO_COPY = &H2

Sub Sample()
    Dim path1 As String, path2 As String

    path1 = "\\xxxfileserve\department$\DBA\Opers\All Operators\yyy"
    path2 = "\\xxxfileserve\department$\DBA\Opers\All Operators\yyy"

    If CopyFolder(path1, path2) Then
        MsgBox "Copied"
    Else
        MsgBox "Not copied"
    End If
End Sub

Private Function CopyFolder(ByVal sFrom As String, _
ByVal sTo As String) As Boolean
    Dim SHFileOp As SHFILEOPSTRUCT
    On Error GoTo Whoa
    CopyFolder = False
    With SHFileOp
        .wFunc = FO_COPY
        .pFrom = sFrom
        .pTo = sTo
    End With
    SHFileOperation SHFileOp
    CopyFolder = True
    Exit Function
Whoa:
    MsgBox "Following error occurred while copying folder " & sFrom & vbCrLf & _
    Err.Description, vbExclamation, "Error message"
End Function
```

Comment: as an aside - how does one get started to learn Win32 code? I see people using it a lot but what resources should I refer to to start learning about it?

Comment: This is a nice collection of tips by Bob. See if you like it? :) http://bobmoore.mvps.org/Win32/W32main_ns.htm

Comment: +1 not strictly an answer, but a valid if tedious alternative!

Answer (score 1):

### There are some points regarding the `fso.CopyFolder` method:

- *If destination does not exist, the source folder and all its contents gets copied. This is the usual case.*
- *If destination is an existing file, an error occurs.*
- *If destination is a directory, an attempt is made to copy the folder and all its contents.*
- *If a file contained in source already exists in destination, an error occurs if overwrite is False. Otherwise, it will attempt to copy the file over the existing file.*
- *If destination is a read-only directory, an error occurs if an attempt is made to copy an existing read-only file into that directory and overwrite is False.*

***Make sure not any of these are becoming hindrance for your `sub`.***

***But test it another way like this***

```
fso.CopyFolder _
              "\\xxxfileserve\department$\DBA\Opers\All Operators\yyy\*", _
              "\\xxxfileserve\department$\DBA\Cas\yyy", _
              True
```

---

Hope this helps.

Comment: previously it ran ok but this month on running it hangs - so I'm unsure, although relevant, how your comments help?

Comment: @whytheq: Have you bothered to check whether one of those 5 conditions now occurs that may not have occurred previously? That's how this comment might help. In your question, you gave no indication that you had checked this yourself. +1 for good leads toward identifying the problem

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett those conditions are just a straight copy from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg264819.aspx). If I reduce the contents of the folder then the application hangs but eventually completes - but with the full contents it just hangs

Comment: tomorrow I will test using the wildcard alternative suggested by Cylian